# Beamer puts image on bottom part of page, even if there is available space

Tags: beamer, graphics

The following LaTeX-Beamer code

```
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\date{}
\title{Pillole di sicurezza informatica}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \maketitle
   \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{immagini/intro.jpg}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Provides the [following slide](https://germano.fedorapeople.org/canc/latex/s.jpg)

But the image is cutted. The image should be [like this one](https://germano.fedorapeople.org/canc/latex/intro.jpg)
Since there is available space, I do not understand why Beamer puts the image on bottom part of the slide, cutting it. How can I fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a negative vertical distance, but I am not quite sure, if this is a sound solution.

```
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\date{}
\title{Pillole di sicurezza informatica}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \maketitle
 \vspace{-1cm}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (7,5) -- (0,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
% \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{immagini/intro.jpg}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For example if you add an entry for the date, you can see that there is not enough space on the slide ...

If you like to see the intro-picture again the code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\date{}
\title{Pillole di sicurezza informatica}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \maketitle
 \vspace{-1cm}
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{immagini/intro.jpg}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: replacing `\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,5) -- (0,0);` with `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{immagini/intro.jpg}` retuns https://germano.fedorapeople.org/canc/latex/s2.jpg

Comment: You commented out the lines with the tikzpicture-environment, too?

Comment: I have not commented `\begin{tikzpicture}` `end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Then please see the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`beamer` does not place the image directly under your title, because the space is not really available. It contains for example the date you set to be `\date{}`. But you could redefine the title page to free this room

```
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\date{}
\title{Pillole di sicurezza informatica}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip2em\par
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*(please note, you don't need `graphicx` with beamer)*

Comment: I think this is more or less the same answer as above, isn't it?

Comment: @Jürgen Sorry, I did not see your second version, only the one with tikz.

Comment: No problem; I added the second part just a few minutes before you posted your answer.